# Не работают члены-методы iostream( cin.unself() , cout.self() и др. ). Почему?

Tags: c++, codelite

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream pict("picture.png", ios_base::binary);
    if (!pict) cerr << "Невозможно открыть файл";
    while (pict) {
        int i;
        pict.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int));
        cout << hex << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Также код, представленный в книге Бьёрна Страуструпа "Программирование. Принципы и практика использования с++", не работает:

```
...
cin.unself(ios::dec);
cin.unself(ios::oct);
cin.unself(ios::hex);
...
```

Компилятор говорит, что нет такой член-функции.

Предполагаю, что дело в стандарте языка, который я использую. Если это так, то прошу объяснить как его сменить в codelite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете селфи с флагами :)

`setf` - от *set flag*

Соответственно, `unsetf`.

Посмотрите внимательно в книге, как там написано.

По первой части - см. [здесь](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) заголовочный файл к исходникам из данной книги. Сохраните его, и включите в свой код

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
```

и все будет работать.

Comment: Вы правы. Спасибо. Но что не так с моим кодом?

Comment: Не трогайте вопрос после того, как его задали - вы попытались убрать вопрос, на который я ответил - зачем? Просто выставить меня кретином, который отвечает на то, что не спрашивают? По вашему коду - нет у вас этой функции (или макроса) `as_bytes()`, вот компилятор и не понимает, что вы хотите.

Comment: Простите. Я посчитал эту часть не информативной и не корректной с моей стороны.

Comment: Страуструп пишет в книге, что использует свой заголовочный файл, в котором определяет массу вспомогательных функций. Не помню точно, где его надо брать, но его таки надо взять и использовать при компиляции исходников из книги.

Comment: Я нашёл определение функции as_bytes(), поэтому предлагаю закрыть этот вопрос

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.